How to handle a UnknownHostException from an async Quarkus Rest Client method?
In a Quarkus application, a Rest client MyClient is calling an external API. To make the call async, it returns a Uni (from Smallrye Mutiny). The external service url is dynamic. Therefore the client is created at runtime using the QuarkusRestClientBuilder.
A service MyService uses MyClient and provides some basic failure handling.
A test for MyService is testing whether it can handle an invalid url.
A java.net.UnknownHostException is thrown but it is not passed to the onFailure().transform(..) function causing the test to fail with an exception!
The stack trace show it does do some kind of onFailure handling (at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:55)), but it is not ending up in onFailure transformation in the MyService class.
How to properly handle these kind of exceptions for Rest clients?
Why is Mutiny not properly passing the exception to the onFailure handler?
What have I done wrong?
Note: the creation of the client with MyClient.createClient(aUrl) is successful with an invalid url. The test fails on the client.getVersions(..) call.
Also note: the test does not fail on the assertFailedWith due to a different exception being thrown than expected. The test really fails with an exception caught by JUnit.
Similarly, when testing the MyClient to verify it fails when connection is refused, the test fails with an java.net.ConnectException instead of returning a failed Uni.
Code sample:
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyClient {

    static MyClient createClient(URI versionsUrl) {
        return QuarkusRestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .baseUri(versionsUrl)
                .build(MyClient.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Uni<Response<List<Version>>> getVersions(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String authorization);
}

public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(String endpoint, String message, Throwable cause) {
        super("Error while calling " + endpoint + ": " + message, cause);
    }
}



@ApplicationScoped
public class MyService {

    public Uni<Response<List<Version>>> getVersions(URI versionsUrl, Token authToken) {
        var client = MyClient.createClient(versionsUrl);

        return client.getVersions(authToken.value())
                .onFailure().transform(failure -> new MyException("Versions", failure.getMessage(), failure));
    }
}


@QuarkusTest
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
class MyServiceTest {

    @Inject
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void should_fail_when_versions_url_is_invalid() {
        var someToken = new Token("some-token");
        var subscriber = myService.getVersions(URI.create("https://invalid.url"), someToken)
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());

        subscriber.assertCompleted()
                .assertFailedWith(MspException.class, "Failed to get versions from client system");
    }
}

@QuarkusTest
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
class MyClientTest {

    @Test
    public void myclient_should_fail_when_connection_refused() {
        var client = MyClient.createClient(URI.create("http://localhost:1234"));

        var versions = client.getVersions(TEST_TOKEN)
                .subscribe().withSubscriber(UniAssertSubscriber.create());

        versions.assertFailed();
    }
}

Full stack trace:
2024-05-23 10:16:39,849 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.com.cor.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Restarting handler chain for exception exception: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: invalid.url: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$2.accept(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:228)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$2.accept(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:220)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.UniCallbackSubscriber.onFailure(UniCallbackSubscriber.java:62)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:37)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onFailure(FutureImpl.java:188)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitFailure$1(FutureBase.java:75)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.execute(ContextImpl.java:298)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:171)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitFailure(FutureBase.java:72)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:278)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.lambda$doRequest$4(HttpClientImpl.java:398)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Endpoint.lambda$getConnection$0(Endpoint.java:52)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.handle(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:162)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.handle(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:123)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:321)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool$ConnectFailed$1.run(SimpleConnectionPool.java:380)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Task.runNextTasks(Task.java:43)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.CombinerExecutor.submit(CombinerExecutor.java:91)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.execute(SimpleConnectionPool.java:244)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.acquire(SimpleConnectionPool.java:639)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.acquire(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:166)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.requestConnection2(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:173)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientHttpEndpointBase.requestConnection(ClientHttpEndpointBase.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Endpoint.getConnection(Endpoint.java:41)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.doRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:368)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.doRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:325)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$5.lambda$apply$0(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:462)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.AsyncResultUni.subscribe(AsyncResultUni.java:31)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemConsume.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume.subscribe(UniOnItemConsume.java:30)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:110)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:88)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler.handle(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler.handle(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.invokeHandler(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualRunnable.run(SlowContextualRunnable.java:19)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:38)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:35)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:261)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: invalid.url: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1221)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1816)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1806)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1676)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1578)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:220)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:171)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:148)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.handleConnect(ChannelProvider.java:152)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.connect(ChannelProvider.java:103)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.connect(ChannelProvider.java:89)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.connectInternal2(NetClientImpl.java:309)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.lambda$connectInternal$2(NetClientImpl.java:275)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.addListener(FutureImpl.java:231)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.onComplete(FutureImpl.java:199)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.connectInternal(NetClientImpl.java:273)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.connect(HttpChannelConnector.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.httpConnect(HttpChannelConnector.java:148)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.connect(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:82)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.connect(SimpleConnectionPool.java:253)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool$Acquire$3.run(SimpleConnectionPool.java:595)
    ... 52 more

2024-05-23 10:17:03,365 DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.cli.han.ClientErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Failure: GET https://invalid.url, Error[java.net.UnknownHostException: invalid.url: nodename nor servname provided, or not known]: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: invalid.url: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$2.accept(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:228)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$2.accept(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:220)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.UniCallbackSubscriber.onFailure(UniCallbackSubscriber.java:62)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onFailure(UniOperatorProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.AsyncResultUni.lambda$subscribe$1(AsyncResultUni.java:37)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onFailure(FutureImpl.java:188)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitFailure$1(FutureBase.java:75)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.execute(ContextImpl.java:298)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:171)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitFailure(FutureBase.java:72)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryFail(FutureImpl.java:278)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.lambda$doRequest$4(HttpClientImpl.java:398)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Endpoint.lambda$getConnection$0(Endpoint.java:52)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.handle(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:162)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.handle(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:123)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:328)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.emit(ContextImpl.java:321)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool$ConnectFailed$1.run(SimpleConnectionPool.java:380)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Task.runNextTasks(Task.java:43)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.CombinerExecutor.submit(CombinerExecutor.java:91)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.execute(SimpleConnectionPool.java:244)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.acquire(SimpleConnectionPool.java:639)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint$Request.acquire(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:166)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.requestConnection2(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:173)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.ClientHttpEndpointBase.requestConnection(ClientHttpEndpointBase.java:49)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.Endpoint.getConnection(Endpoint.java:41)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:51)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.doRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:368)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.doRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:325)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:184)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler$5.lambda$apply$0(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:462)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.AsyncResultUni.subscribe(AsyncResultUni.java:31)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemConsume.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume.subscribe(UniOnItemConsume.java:30)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:110)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:88)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler.handle(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSendRequestHandler.handle(ClientSendRequestHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.invokeHandler(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
    at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualRunnable.run(SlowContextualRunnable.java:19)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:38)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers.ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler$1$1.handle(ClientSwitchToRequestContextRestHandler.java:35)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:261)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:59)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: invalid.url: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:52)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformResolver.lookupByName(InetAddress.java:1221)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1816)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1806)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1676)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1578)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:220)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:171)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:148)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.handleConnect(ChannelProvider.java:152)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.connect(ChannelProvider.java:103)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ChannelProvider.connect(ChannelProvider.java:89)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.connectInternal2(NetClientImpl.java:309)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.lambda$connectInternal$2(NetClientImpl.java:275)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$4.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:176)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:66)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.addListener(FutureImpl.java:231)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.onComplete(FutureImpl.java:199)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetClientImpl.connectInternal(NetClientImpl.java:273)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.connect(HttpChannelConnector.java:90)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpChannelConnector.httpConnect(HttpChannelConnector.java:148)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.connect(SharedClientHttpStreamEndpoint.java:82)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool.connect(SimpleConnectionPool.java:253)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.pool.SimpleConnectionPool$Acquire$3.run(SimpleConnectionPool.java:595)
    ... 52 more


Problem was in how the test was asserting the failures.
On UniAssertSubscriber the assertCompleted() and assertFailed() functions do NOT wait for the Uni to complete.
The documentation on writing tests for Uni/Multi is very minimal and the shown examples only work because the Uni/Multi is directly completed.
To correct way is to use awaitFailure() or awaitItem().
So in the MyServiceTest the assertion should be
  subscriber.awaitFailure(throwable -> {
    assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(MspException.class);
  });

and in MyClientTest
  versions.awaitFailure(throwable -> {
    assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(ConnectException.class);
  });

With this both tests now succeed.
So the Uni does correctly fail as expected.
